# CSS: how to cascade class-specific style to children

Tags: html, css, inheritance

Suppose I have an HTML table that has been assigned to the class `dependency_table`.

How can I style the `tr`, `th`, and `td` children of that that *specific* table without having to put `class="dependency_table"` in all of the child tags?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
/* --- DEPENDENCY TABLE STYLING --- */
.dependency_table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: pink;
}

.dependency_table ~ td {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    text-align: center;
}

.dependency_table ~ th{
     background: #DFDFDF;  /* Darken header a bit */
     font-weight: bold;
}
```

The general sibling selector hasn't worked for me yet with this syntax. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: The children of table are not its siblings... Just use a space after the class: `.dependency_table tr` `.dependency_table td` `.dependency_table th`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to do this:

```
/* --- DEPENDENCY TABLE STYLING --- */
.dependency_table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: pink;
}

.dependency_table td {
    #your style
}

.dependency_table th{
     #your style
}

.dependency_table tr{
         #your style
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to cover more tags at once:

```css
.dependency_table td, .dependency_table tr, .dependency_table th{
  #your style
}
```